# Generating random data-attributes for tabbed content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create random numbers so that they can be assigned to each class instance.

The reason I'm doing this is because I have tabbed content and when I have two instances of the tabbed modules, it resets the data attributes. For example:

- My page has content with three tabs. These tabs currently have the `data-item` attribute of 1,2 and 3.
- I then add another tab module of three tabs. When I add this module to the page, the `data-item` resets to 1.
- In short, two tabs exist on page which has the `data-item` attribute of 1, 2 and 3.
- So when I click on one tab, the other tab (which has the duplicated `data-item`) changes too.

When a user clicks a tab, it displays an image assigned to that section (they're linked through data-item).

So I'm trying to generate unique `data-items` and assign them to both a `.tab` and an `.image`. This will pair them up.

However, with my current approach, it's assigning them to all of the tabs.

**Current approach**:

```js
$(function() {

 // generate random id for data item
 var randomnNmber = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);

 $('.imageWrapper .image').each(function () {
  $(this).attr('data-item',randomnNmber);
 });

 $('.tabsWrapper .tab').each(function () {
  $(this).attr('data-item',randomnNmber);
 });

 $(".tab").on("click", function(){
  var tabID  = $(this).attr("data-item");
  event.stopPropagation();

  $('.image').removeClass('active');
  $('.image[data-item = '+tabID+']').addClass('active');
  $(".tab").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
 });

});
```

```html
<div class="tabbedContent">

  <div class="imageWrapper">
     <div class="image">
      <!-- image -->
     </div>
     <div class="image">
      <!-- image -->
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabsWrapper">
    <div class="tab">
      <!-- tab text here -->
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <!-- tab text here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Easier to change your data-item=1 (,2,3) variable so that it's a global variable rather than tab-container specific.  Then your 2nd tab will be 4,5,6 and problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** random numbers are not guaranteed to be unique.

It's very likely that you will get duplicate numbers using this method.
You could add an array to store "used" numbers and check that to reduce duplicates.

But to answer your question:

---

Your code generates a single random number at the top and then assigns that single number too all (in turn) (as you've found).

You need to regenerate the number each time, but to get them in pairs you need a single loop.

I've also converted to `.data()` rather than `.attr("data-`

Updated snippet:

```js
$(function() {

  var images = $('.imageWrapper .image');
  var tabs = $('.tabsWrapper .tab');

  if (images.length !== tabs.length)
    alert("tabs and images don't match");
  else {
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
      // generate a different random id for each pair
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
      images.eq(i).data("item", randomNumber);
      tabs.eq(i).data("item", randomNumber);
    }
  }

  $(".tab")
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .on("click", function() {
      var tabID = $(this).data("item");
      event.stopPropagation();

      $('.image').removeClass('active');
      $(".image").filter(function() { 
            return $(this).data('item') == tabID
        }).addClass('active');
      $(".tab").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });

});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabbedContent">

  <div class="imageWrapper">
    <div class="image">
      image 1
      <!-- image -->
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      image 2
      <!-- image -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabsWrapper">
    <div class="tab">
      tab 1
      <!-- tab text here -->
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      tab 2
      <!-- tab text here -->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Right, I see the logic, thanks. However, the issue I'm having with this approach is demo'd here: https://jsfiddle.net/ptsdofhr/. By default, when you load  the fiddle, its state is correct. It's showing two 'tabbedContent` modules, however, when you click on another tab, it'll hide the image for the `tabbedContent` above`. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's caused by this line `$('.image').removeClass('active');` (and tab equivalent).  You need to also pair up your tabs and image contains - in your case these are already paired up as they're in `tabbedContent` giving `$(this).closest(".tabbedContent").find(".image,.tab").removeClass("active");` - updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a2ug9mL8/

Comment: Also, if you're looping through all of the tabs+images in one go, you don't need the random number, just use the loop index:  `https://jsfiddle.net/a2ug9mL8/1/`

Comment: Finally, if your tabs and images are all wrapped in a `tabbedContent` and they always appear in the same order (implied as you're adding the `data-item` *after* they've been generated, so they must be to match) - then you don't need `data-item` at all and can use `$(this).index()` with `$(this).closest(".tabbedContent")`: updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a2ug9mL8/2/

Comment: Normally, you would add the `data-item=` in the HTML itself (manually or based on some server-side key) and pair the tab+content(image in your case) via the matching data-item.